# compute $\int _0^1 \cdots \int _0^1F_n(x_1,\cdots, x_n)dx_1\cdots dx_n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ strictly increasing function and $F_n(x_1,\cdots, x_n):=n(1-\max_{1\leq k \leq n}{\{f(x_k)\}})$
Then, compute $\int _0^1 \cdots \int _0^1F_n(x_1,\cdots, x_n)dx_1\cdots dx_n$

I tried compute that $\sum \int _{x_{i_1}<\cdots <x_{i_n}}F_n$ but I couldn't.

Comment: Have you tried $n=2$ (and $n=1$)?

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a Lebesgue integral? I'm thinking: $$\int_0^1 n(1-f(x))\chi_{\forall k: 0 \le x_k\le x} (x_1, \cdots, x_n)dx$$ My notation may be a bit off, but basically, multiply by the $n$th dimensional volume that satisfies that the max component is $x$. This kind of turns it into a function of one variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the integration domain to $0 \leqslant x_1 \leqslant \ldots \leqslant x_n \leqslant 1$ and integrate by $x_1, \ldots, x_{n - 1}$. Given the extra multiplier $n$ in your $F_n$, you should get
$$n^2 \int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \big(1 - f(x)\big)\ dx.$$

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\PM}{\mathbb P}$*A probabilistic approach*

Let $U_1,...,U_n \sim \mathcal U[0,1]$ i.i.d. then you are interested in:
\begin{align}
I_n:=n\E[1-\max\{ f(U_1),...,f(U_n)\}] = n -n\E[\max\{ f(U_1),...,f(U_n)\}]
\end{align}
One knows that for $f(0)\leq x\leq f(1)$:
\begin{align}
\PM(\max\{ f(U_1),...,f(U_n)\}\leq x)=\PM(f(U_1)\leq x)^n = \PM(U_1 \leq f^{-1}(x) )^n = \left(f^{-1}(x)\right)^n  
\end{align}
Hence: 
\begin{align}
n\E[\max\{ f(U_1),...,f(U_n)\}] = n^2\int^{f(1)}_{f(0)} x\cdot \left(f^{-1}(x)\right)^{n-1}  \cdot \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}\,dx
\end{align}
Set $u=f^{-1}(x)$ so that we get:
\begin{align}
n\E[\max\{ f(U_1),...,f(U_n)\}] = n^2 \int^1_0  f(u) u^{n-1}\,du
\end{align}
Hence:
\begin{align}
I_n = n-n^2 \int^1_0  f(u) u^{n-1}\,du
\end{align}

*Oh, one last remark, where did we use the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing?*

Comment: I would be happy to improve this answer, dear downvoter. Please tell me what is wrong!